# Finding rows in Pandas Data Frame with Same Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I currently have a large Data Frame consisting of over 1,0000 rows and 600 columns. The table is indexed on the left by identity and each column is a position. The value of each point in the grid is either a 0 or a 1. I would like to be able to fish out and group the Identities by determining which ones have identical patterns of 0's and 1's within their rows.

For example:

```
print df.table
ID#1   0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
ID#2   0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
ID#3   1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
ID#4   0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
ID#5   1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
ID#6   0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

df.table.'GROUP' returns

[(ID#1,ID#4), (ID#2,ID#6), (ID#3,ID#5)]
```

Comment: Will pd.DataFrame.duplicated() http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html suit your needs?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [39]: data = """ID#1   0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
ID#2   0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
ID#3   1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
ID#4   0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
ID#5   1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
ID#6   0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
"""

In [40]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data),header=None,sep='\s+',index_col=0)

In [41]: df['compressed'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join([ str(v) for v in x ]),1)

In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 compressed
0                                         
ID#1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  010100101
ID#2  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  001010101
ID#3  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  100010110
ID#4  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  010100101
ID#5  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  100010110
ID#6  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  001010101

In [43]: df.groupby('compressed').apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist())
Out[43]: 
compressed
001010101     [ID#2, ID#6]
010100101     [ID#1, ID#4]
100010110     [ID#3, ID#5]
dtype: object
```

Here are 2 more reshapings you can do (do this before you add the 'compressed' column)

Create a Series with the valuess being a tuple of the 1 positions

```
In [45]: pd.concat([ Series([ tuple(x[x.astype(bool)].index.tolist()) ], index=[row]) for (row,x) in df.iterrows() ])
Out[45]: 
ID#1    (2, 4, 7, 9)
ID#2    (3, 5, 7, 9)
ID#3    (1, 5, 7, 8)
ID#4    (2, 4, 7, 9)
ID#5    (1, 5, 7, 8)
ID#6    (3, 5, 7, 9)
dtype: object
```

Create a frame that has a column for each 1 position

```
In [46]: DataFrame(dict([ (row,x[x.astype(bool)].index.tolist()) for (row,x) in df.iterrows() ])).T
Out[46]: 
      0  1  2  3
ID#1  2  4  7  9
ID#2  3  5  7  9
ID#3  1  5  7  8
ID#4  2  4  7  9
ID#5  1  5  7  8
ID#6  3  5  7  9
```

Comment: thanks Jeff! That was extremely helpful, just one alteration I'd like to ask you, if instead I wanted to make a column instead of compressed that consisted of a list of the positions at which the 1s occurred for example for ID number one the compressed value would appear as ['2','4','7','9'] and so on. If you could help it would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

data = """ID#1   0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
ID#2   0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
ID#3   1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
ID#4   0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
ID#5   1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
ID#6   0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
"""

Variation on a theme.

```
df = read_csv(StringIO(data),header=None,sep='\s+',index_col=range (1,10))

df.groupby(level = range(9)).apply(lambda x: x[0].tolist())


1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1    [ID#2, ID#6]
   1  0  1  0  0  1  0  1    [ID#1, ID#4]
1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0    [ID#3, ID#5]
dtype: object
```